# asp:RequiredFieldValidator validation based on conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have validation as below but only like to triggered if the checkbox is ticked.

```asp
<!-- TextBox and its validator -->
Name: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server"
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
        Text="*"
        ErrorMessage="Name is required" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" />
```

Can I get it done using asp:RequiredFieldValidator?
I only like to validate if a certain condition matched.
Currently it is validating every time the 'Save' button is clicked.

Comment: Use a `CustomValidator` instead

Comment: Any example? My validator needs interaction based on multiple controls and conditions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this easily by adding the following javascript on Client side.

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator1"), true); or
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator2"), false);
```

Comment: Page.IsValid will be false in this case

Answer (score 40):

Use a custom validator instead:

```asp
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv1" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Name is required"
        Text="*"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ValidateEmptyText="True" 
        ClientValidationFunction="validate" />
```

and the script (just checking a checkbox and the textbox value as example; you can use custom logic):

```asp
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(s,args){
        if(document.getElementById("<%= checkboxId.ClientID %>").checked){
            args.IsValid = args.Value != '';

        }
        else{
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will do the client-side validation. If you need server validation also, add the `OnServerValidate` attribute, and a handler on code behind. [See here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Comment: Note: if you are wondering why it doesn't fire on an empty textbox, you have to set `ValidateEmptyText="True"` on the CustomValidator.

Comment: Just remember if you have a ValidationGroup, don't miss add ValidationGroup property in the CustomValidator objet

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if(CheckBox.Checked)
   {
       RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
       RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = "anything";
       Button1.ValidationGroup = "anything";// your save button

   }
   else
   {
       RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;
       RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = string.Empty;
       Button1.ValidationGroup = string.Empty; // save button
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't have the code with me but i don't think this will work since we are doing client validation and the code behind code won't get hit?

Comment: Same as my comment below. I have confirmed what in_visible is saying. This works until the validator fires. Once it fires, it can't postback to disable the validator unless you satisfy it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
protected void RequiredFieldValidator1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
     {
         RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
     }
     else if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
     {
         RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Similar to my response for the other answer.
"Don't have the code with me but i don't think this will work since we are doing client validation and the code behind code won't get hit?"

Comment: This works until the validator fires. Once it fires, it can't postback to disable the validator unless you satisfy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enabled/Disabled the **RequiredFieldValidator** from the Javascript/jQuery. 
For your condition, When **Checkbox is checked** :- Just call the javascript function to enabled the **RequiredFieldValidator** and when its Uncheck just disabled the RequiredFieldValidator.

For other Conditions like Dropdown index change, textbox value change and radio button selection change you can call its onchange, onblur, onclick respectively and 
After executing the required condition you can **Enabled/Disabled** the **RequiredFieldValidator**.

Hope this help you.