# How to disable/enable validator immediately after dropdownlist change ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#

Id like to know how to get the validator disabled after a change in drop-down list value without having to press submit:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAttendance" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="Id" runat="server"
                                        DataSourceID="sdsAppointmentStatuses" CssClass="form-control"  
                                        >
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtAttendanceNotes" runat="server" Rows="2" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNotes" runat="server" ErrorMessage="A Note is required with this status" 
                                        Display="Dynamic" CssClass="text-error" ControlToValidate="txtAttendanceNotes" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(vcontol, dropDownList) {
    var returnStr = '<%=NotesData() %>';
    var bb = JSON.parse(returnStr);

    for (var i = 0; i < bb.length; i++)
    {
        if (dropDownList.value == bb[i]) {
            vcontol.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that solves the same question. Substitute the checkbox for your drop down value.
[asp:RequiredFieldValidator validation based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791106/asprequiredfieldvalidator-validation-based-on-conditions)